Schengen Visa Cancelled Before the Trip
More than 2 years ago I had got a Schengen visa from Switzerland. However due to last minute changes we amended our travel to Croatia and Dubrovnik. At the airport check in counter the flight members notified the embassy for the same and immediately our visa was cancelled on account of “visa shopping”. We did not end up travelling to Europe and instead we went to Mauritius where visa was available on arrival. During this time, we received a notice at home from the Swiss embassy asking us to report to the embassy or our visa would be cancelled. Given we were anyway out of town we did not end up going. Now we are planning a trip to France - does this incident regarding the Swiss visa need to be reported in the French visa application? This was completely unintentional and we eventually did not even end up using the visa. We are running tight on time so any suggestions that can make the application better while ensuring we get the visa on time as we will not have enough bandwidth to reapply or appeal.

What are your nationality and residence, if different from nationality? In the third sentence, which embassy was notified, Switzerland or Croatia? And your visa was canceled but then the Swiss embassy said they would cancel your visa (that was already canceled)? Also see related question Re-Apply for Schengen Visa after rejection in a different country?

The ground staff of the airline notified the Swiss embassy? That would be the first time I hear that one… Where were you departing from, and what was the airline?

Since the French will see your previous visa application in the VIS (Visa Information System), adding a statement as to what happened would be wise.

Yes the ground staff notified the immigration officer. We were travelling Lufthansa and first point of immigration was Munich. The immigration officer notified Swiss embassy. It was over the weekend so we only got a notice on Monday and didn't end up visiting the embassy as we were not in town then. So our visa was cancelled but the notice from Swiss embassy was stating that if we would not want to be cancelled (perhaps retain that visa) we need to visit the embassy.

To add further this was 2 years ago. So any idea what time period is checked for historical track record?

@EA21 5 years after the last activity.
